# Get values from an array given a list of coordinates/locations with Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a first 3D numpy array and a second numpy array containing the locations (coordinates) of elements of the first I am interested in.

```
first = np.array([[[100, 101, 102],
                  [103, 104, 105],
                  [106, 107, 108]],

                 [[109, 110, 111],
                  [112, 113, 114],
                  [115, 116, 117]],

                 [[118, 119, 120],
                  [121, 122, 123],
                  [124, 125, 126]]])


second = np.array([[0, 1, 0],
                   [1, 1, 0],
                   [1, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0],

                   [0, 1, 1],
                   [1, 1, 1],
                   [1, 0, 1],
                   [0, 0, 1]])

result = np.array([103, 112, 109, 100, 104, 113, 110, 101])
```

The result I would like: all values located at the positions contained in the second array.

Using `first[second]` does not do the trick. I would like to avoid looping.

Comment: What about using `np.where(second)` to then perform an access to `first` from the result?

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I am not sure if I fully understand. `first[np.where(second)]` does not work either.

Comment: Show us `first` and what the expected output should be. "It does not work" is unacceptable.

Comment: What are the 0/1 values in `second` supposed to index?  The relation of your 2d `second` to a unknown 3d is not clear.  You may have to show "looping" code first to show us clearly what you are trying to do.

Comment: I updated the question using Mark's answer. I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a flat index array from your `second` array with [`numpy.ravel_multi_index()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel_multi_index.html). This can then be passed to [`take()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html#numpy.take_along_axis) which will give you a flat list of values.

Given a starting array:

```
import numpy as np
m = np.arange(100, 127).reshape([3, 3, 3])
```

of

```
[[[100 101 102]
  [103 104 105]
  [106 107 108]]

 [[109 110 111]
  [112 113 114]
  [115 116 117]]

 [[118 119 120]
  [121 122 123]
  [124 125 126]]]
```

and your indexes:

```
second = np.array(
    [[0, 1, 0],
     [1, 1, 0],
     [1, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0],

     [0, 1, 1],
     [1, 1, 1],
     [1, 0, 1],
     [0, 0, 1]])

i = np.ravel_multi_index(second.T, m.shape)
m.take(i)
```

results in:

```
array([103, 112, 109, 100, 104, 113, 110, 101])
```